# Countdown don't stay run if close tabs

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer

I'm learning to make a countdown, and I find a guide on the Internet. but when the page is closed countdown stops and if I open the page again countdown runs again, I want to make the countdown continues to run even if the page is closed
 http://jsfiddle.net/FnsY4/

```js
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays)
{
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
function getCookie(cname)
{
var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) 
  {
  var c = ca[i].trim();
  if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
  }
return "";
}

//check existing cookie
cook=getCookie("my_cookie");

if(cook==""){
   //cookie not found, so set seconds=60
   var seconds = 60;
}else{
     seconds = cook;
     console.log(cook);
}

function secondPassed() {
    var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
    var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
    }
    //store seconds to cookie
    setCookie("my_cookie",seconds,5); //here 5 is expiry days
    
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" +    remainingSeconds;
    if (seconds == 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Buzz Buzz";
    } else {    
        seconds--;
    }
}

var countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="countdown" class="timer"></span>
```

Comment: you need to develop the timer on server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the countdown to be effective even if the tab is closed, you'll have to reconsider it with two (or more) options:

- You do this server side and the countdown is displayed in the client window but processed in the server
- You set your countdown to a given date (let's say) 16/12/2014 11:00:00 am then make some calculus for the display. As the given date is constant, no matter how many times the countdown will be closed/opened, it'll always be true.
- Once you start the countdown, you save the ending datetime to a cookie and restore the countdown from it the next time you open the page.